# How to set window context for node HTTP server

Tags: node.js, http

I'm using Node.js HTTP module to create a server, How do I set the window context in a HTTP server?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. *How do I set the window context in a HTTP server?* - what's the meaning of this?

Comment: @estus Thanks for your reply. I am running my app using node HTTP server. To start my app expecting some configuration and context(on witch context app is running) values in `window.config` and  `window.context`variable. So how can i set those values while running using node HTTP server.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean. If you want these values to be available on *client side*, you should output something like `<script>window.config = ...</script>` in HTML template.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use global variable like `window` in browser, you should use `global` in Node.js instead.

for example:

in **browser**

```js
window.foo = 'bar'
```

in **Node.js**

```js
global.foo = 'bar'
```

by the way, If you wanna use a same name variable which can be used in Node.js server or browser, you can use `globalThis`.

in **browser**

```js
globalThis === window // true
```

in **Node.js**

```js
globalThis === global // true
```